# Migrating existing Java and Flash applications to Android (Google TV)

Tags: java, android, flash, television

I have a client-server multigame suite for PC ("kind of" cross-platform using cygwin), which is developed in Java(game menus and database management), C++ (server side), and adobe Flash (game graphics & interaction).

I have never tried to develop for android, so i have no experience.
I am thinking of migrating this suite to google TV. So i would like someone with android experience to give a clue on the following :

1) Is it going to be easy to migrate the Java application to an Android application?

2) What kind of Flash support does Android have? Can it load directly swf applications? Does it have to load swf's through browser?

3) Can i find any kind of performance indexes for google TV hardware? Anyone that tested Logitech Revue or Sony Internet TV Blu-ray Disc Player?

4) Any other suggestions or links that can give me more helpful info?

Thanks in advance.
Constantine.

Comment: Concerning 2. You can create fullscale android apps with air 2.x and flash builder 4.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

agreed Air is your best bet to create a android flash CS4, CS5 and CS5.5 that will put everything you need together.

I know there are some limitations on Flash AIR development for Android but may have changed since I last touched it (Flash CS4), as far as Google TV goes I am not sure, I did hear that previous Android Apps should work with Google TV, so if you can make a app in Flash AIR to Android it should be ok.

From getting setup today and looking at things, I know that Google TV supports Flash 10.1, I know the logic tech keyboard may give you the advantage you may be looking for games if you are using various keys, a little bit harder to work with the remotes for gaming but I'm sure someone will figure it out